# How to Access the Map values from the Remote Invoking

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, remote-action

Friends,
I have used the below code. But I dont know how to get the values from the map in Javascript.

Code Snippet:
**Apex**

```
@RemoteAction
     public static Map<string,Account> FetchAccount()
      {
     Map<string,Account> Accountmap = <Loaded the Account name and Id>
     return Accountmap;      
     }
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page>
<script>

 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.handler.FetchAccount}',
                function (result, event) {

               var AccountValue= [
                  ['ID', Account Name] // How to store the name Id here
                   ];
                 }
                 );

</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: adrian Yes it is method. I have mentioned in my posting.

Comment: That's not what I asked.... whatever it's immaterial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below

```
var AccountValue= [result.length];
               for (var key in result) {
                        AccountValue[0][0] = result[key].Id
                        AccountValue[0][1] = result[key].Name;
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

RemoteAction should return json object which contains map of accounts, you can use usual for loop:

```
if (event.status) {
    console.log(result);

    for (var key in result) {
        console.log(key + " " + result[key].Name);
        var AccountValue = result[key];
        console.log(AccountValue);
    }
```

**Updated:**

If you need specific JSON, you can build it in APEX:

```
@RemoteAction
global static list<list<String>> getAccounts(String accountName) {
    accounts = new list<list<String>>();
    for (account acc :[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account limit 3]){
        accounts.add(new list<String>{acc.id, acc.name});
    }
    return accounts;
}
```

VF:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.lenght; i++){
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array [ Array[2], Array[2], Array[2] ]
Array [ "00136000002lG10AAE", "Wonderland" ]
...
```

Comment: How to add in my  var AccountValue= [
                  ['ID', Account Name] 
                   ];

Comment: result[key] is a single object with id and name. Do you mean, you want to use object like {"001xxxxxxxx", "Name"} ?

Comment: not above, I have mentioned in my posting. I want to use as the array list.

Comment: var AccountValues= [
                    
                    ['00130000003Sjh', Asia Account],
                    ['00130000003ssh',NewYark Account],
                    
                ];